# How to remove/mutate things (shells, aliases) in nushell

Tags: nushell

I'm using `shells` and `enter` to manage a "dirstack". I want to "popd" to **remove dirs** I've added.

I also have some aliases that I no longer want in my session. How do I **delete the aliases**?

I've tried things like `drop` but if the dirs and aliases are possibly immutable, how do I change them (without starting a new session)? Feels like there should be commands like `leave` (or `unenter` vs `enter`) and `unalias` (vs `alias`).

Comment: Looking at the list of built-in aliases, I now notice `dexit` which appears to drop a `shells` dir entry (though I can't find it in any docs). So maybe that half is solved for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can "Hide definitions in the current scope" with the `hide` [command](https://www.nushell.sh/commands/docs/hide.html).

```bash
alias ll = ls -al
hide ll
ll
```

```
Error: nu::shell::external_command

  × External command failed
   ╭─[entry #49:1:1]
 1 │ ll
   · ─┬
   ·  ╰── did you mean 'all'?
   ╰────
  help: No such file or directory (os error 2)
```

As for the `pushd`/`popd` equivalency (see the [docs](https://www.nushell.sh/contributor-book/shells.html#shells)), you can enter a new shell with `enter`, and exit it with `dexit`. You can inspect the table with `shells` or `g`, and activate the next or previous directory with `n` and `p`.